# Ruby on Rails - simple datatable (followed step-by-step instructions) isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails app and I'm simply trying to get datatables working. Not trying to do anything complicated. I followed the guide just as it is on the GitHub, but yet it's not working. Here are my files

```
#Gemfile
...
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
...
```

.

```
#app/stylesheets/application.css
/*
 *= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_style
*/
```

.

```
   #app/javascript/application.js
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
    //= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require_tree .
```

.

```
   #app/javascript/finding.js.coffee
    jQuery ->
      $("#findings").dataTable()
```

.

```
   #views/findings/index.html.erb
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive" id="findings">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th align="center">Finding Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <tbody>
        <% @findings.each do |finding| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= finding.name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is just like it looks in the guide, but yet it's not working. I can see that my table shows the datatable, but I can't sort anything. The only thing that works is the search, and that's just partially.

For example, I can search for something, but when I backspace to clear it out, it still shows the item that I searched for (only).

If I inspect element and bring up the console in Google Chrome, here's the error that I see when I simply load the index.html.erb page

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

I don't understand it. What can I try next? It seems that I have just set up a basic example and can't get this to work. I am also using Bootstrap.

Comment: I even just created a whole new rails app, followed step 1-3 on the github page, gave my table the id, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you try, putting the initalize for datatable in a document.ready? Plus, check structure of the table as well, since datatable is pretty strict on it as well.